# how to add button in google map infowindow in ionic 3 application

Tags: html, google-maps, dom, ionic3

This is the part of code in my ionic 3 application.

```
            google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', (event)=>{
              if (event) {
                point = event.latLng;
              }
              this.fence = fence
              this.geoInfowindow.setContent(content +
                '<button onclick="this.toEdit()">edit</button>' +
                '<button onclick="this.toDelete()">delete</button>' +
                '<button onclick="this.toEnable()">enable</button>');
              this.geoInfowindow.setPosition(point);
              this.geoInfowindow.open(this.map);
            });

            toEdit(){}

            toDelete(){}

            toEnable(){}
```

When I click the button, I get below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.toEnable is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue? Thanks